# Find degree of differential equation of family of curves described as $y=c(x-c)^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find degree of differential equation of family of curves described as $$y=c(x-c)^2$$

I can see that the order is $1$ but am not able to identify the degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $y=c(x-c)^2$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2c(x-c).....(1)$$$$x-c=\dfrac{1}{2c}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right).....(2)$$$$y=c\left(\dfrac{1}{2c}\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$$$y=c\left(\dfrac{1}{4c^2}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)$$$$c=\dfrac{1}{4y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2.....(3)$$Now plug in $(3)$ in $(1)$ we get,$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\left(\dfrac{1}{4y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1}{4y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)$$$$1=\dfrac{1}{2y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1}{4y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)$$$$1+\dfrac{1}{8y^2}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=\dfrac{x}{2y}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)$$$$8y^2+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=4xy\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
Therefore, $$\mbox{order }=1$$
$$\mbox{degree }=3$$

Comment: What is the theory behind this?  The goal of this method/calculation?  Not trying to be critical, seriously want to know . . . Thanks.  Cheers!

Comment: Just to show my sincerity, ***endorsed (+1)!!!***.  But my queries remain, one mathematician to another; enlighten me if you please! ;)

Comment: @RobertLewis I just brought the equation in terms of $c$ and then substituted it back in the given equation so that I can remove $c$ from the original equation.

Comment: So the idea is to eliminate the constants?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you provide a (preferably online) reference or at least a topic area I can search?

Comment: If you eliminate c by putting its value in $y=c(x-c)^2$ then answer will be different

Comment: @Maverick I mean, we need to plug in the value of $c$ in $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2c(x-c)$

Comment: I guess I want to know what the theory behind all this is?

Comment: Now, we have the differential equation. How could we solve it ? I tried in vain.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Did you really didn't get how to solve this problem?

Comment: @tienlee. Yes, I am serious. I tried in vain to find the general solution. Could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Claude ! Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the OP question. This a comment too long to be edited in the comments section.

In fact, the answer to the OP question was already given by Key Flex, who already found the ODE :
$$8y^2+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=4xy\dfrac{dy}{dx} \tag 1$$
My comment is an answer to a question raised in comments by Claude Leib0vici who I welcome.

The question is : How to solve the ODE $(1)$ ?

Let $y(x)=u(x)^2\quad;\quad y'=2uu'$
$$8u^4+(2uu')^3=4xu^2(2uu')$$
$$u+(u')^3=xu'\tag 2$$
$$u'+3(u')^2u''=u'+xu''$$
$$(3(u')^2-x)u''=0$$
We get two families of solutions :

From $3(u')^2-x=0$ the first family $u=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}x^{3/2}+C$ must be rejected because putting it into Eq.$(2)$ shows that it doesn't agree. This is a non convenient solution introduced by the differentiation of $(2)$.

From $u''=0$ the second family $u=ax+b$ is put into Eq.$(2)$ and agrees if $(ax+b)+a^3=xa$ which implies $b=-a^3$. Thus :
$$u=ax-a^3$$
$$y=(ax-a^3)^2=a^2(x-a^2)$$
Let $a^2=c$
$$y=c(x-c)^2$$
Note that $a$ is not necessarily real, but can be complex. So, the case of negative $c$ is not forgotten.