# Euler Lagrange, weird Second Order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have found the Euler-Langrange equation of the functional:
$$\int_{a}^{b} y'^2+y^4\,\mathrm dx$$
to be $y'' = 2y^3$

How do I solve this non-linear DE?

Comment: I think that the solution of $y''=2y^3$ could involve Jacobi elliptic functions.

Comment: Existence and uniqueness is by the classical Picard theorem, but if you want an explicit answer it doesn't look pretty if W|A is to be trusted http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%3D+2y%5E3

Answer (score 9):

$$y''=2y^3$$
$$2y''y'=4y^3y'$$
$$y^4=y'^2+c_1$$
$$y'=\pm \sqrt{y^4-c_1}$$
$$x=\pm\int \frac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^4-c_1}}+c_2$$
This is an elliptic integral : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html

The inverse function $y(x)$ involves the sn Jacobi elliptic function :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html
$$y(x)= C_1 \text{sn}\left(C_1(x+c_2)\:|\:-1 \right)$$
with $C_1=c_1^{1/4}$

Comment: Hi Jean. Long time no speak !

Comment: Hi Claude ! Not so long time... Three days ago I answered to one of your comments. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871630/find-degree-of-differential-equation-of-family-of-curves-described-as-y-cx-c

Comment: Jean : I think that we must write in the text @xyz in order Mr/Mrs Xyz be notified. This is why I had the feeling that it was long. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'' = 2y^3$$
Substitute 
$$p=\frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} \implies y''=\frac {\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dx}=\frac {\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dy}\frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=p'p$$
Then the equation is separable
$$pp'=2y^3$$
Integrate
$$\int p\,\mathrm dp=2\int y^3\,\mathrm dy$$
$$p^2+K=\frac {y^4}2$$
$$\frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\pm \sqrt {\frac {y^4}2+C}$$
$$.....$$